# Can I install, delete and re-install the same SSL certificate on the same server

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, server, ssl-certificate

Can I install an SSL certificate on a server, test that SSL certificate, delete the certificate and install it again on the same server later? Or will Windows not allow the re-installation because it was already used before, or for any other reason?

Officially, I'm not allowed to install anything before a certain date on this specific server, validation procedure wise. However, the deadline to get everything installed is very harsh. If the provided SSL certificate would appear to be invalid, it would be a complete disaster. That's why I was thinking of unofficially already installing/testing the SSL certificate, deleting it, and re-installing it later on the official day, reducing the risk of not meeting the deadline.

Would that pose a problem?

Comment: It can appear invalid if for any reason the associated private key was lost. Check that you can export this private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically I dont see any problem with installing a certificate, then deleting it and re-installing. The 2nd part of your issue is a little trickier - "Officially, i'm not allowed..." - only you can decide.

Few things to bare in mind if you proceed:
 - There may be a record of you installing/removing the cert in the event/audit logs on the system or elsewhere.
 - SSL certs have a start and end date - will the cert actually be valid when you plan to test it?

Some other options...

If your issue is more to do with where you install the cert to test (ie on a prod machine etc), could you spin up local vm/cloud machine and test the cert on a disposable machine? You can easily spoof DNS locally on a temp server with its hosts file so the local IIS will respond to any name you choose to ensure the SSL will work.

You can also verify an SSL certificate chain with openssl CLI (its also possible via some online tools - but NEVER use a service where it asks you to upload a private key!)